# First Item of Dropdown is Undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, bootstrap-4

I am calling a external JSON file in my script tag. The Dropdown renders the JSON file normally but the element "undefined" is appended to the dropdown values.

This is my JSON File :

```
{
"vendor_name":["User 1", "User 2", "User 3"]
}
```

This is my HTML Code :

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data- 
    toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu vendorDropdown">

    </ul>
</div>
```

This is my Script Tag :

```
<script>
fetch('vendorName.json')
.then(res => res.text())
.then(item => {
    let items = JSON.parse(item)
    let output
    console.log(items)
    items.vendor_name.map(item => {
        output += `
        <li>
        ${item}
        </li>
        `
    });
    $('.vendorDropdown').append(output)
})
</script>
```

This is My Final Output in Dropdown Values :

```
undefined
User 1
User 2
User 3
```

Comment: `let output` is `let output = undefined` so you append a string to undefined....

Comment: Why are you using map as forEach?

Comment: initialize `output` variable.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are initializing `output` is creating an empty element. Instead, it'd be better to initialize it with something like an empty string and then add your values.

`let output = "";` would do.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to initialize `output` to empty string `` instead of simply declaring it (henc `undefined`)?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're appending to your variable called `output`. `output` initially has a value of `undefined`, which is why you see it in your resulting string (after the append). To circumvent this issue you can change this line:

`let output;`

to this:

`let output = '';`

Alternatively, you could do something similar to below, where I used `map` and `join` instead of appending to an independent variable. I used `setTimeout` wrapped in a `Promise` to simulate the `fetch` call

```js
const ulEl = document.querySelector('.vendorDropdown');

const simulateFetch = () => {
  ulEl.innerHTML = 'Fetching JSON. Please wait..';

  //Mock data
  const json = {
    "vendor_name": ["User 1", "User 2", "User 3"]
  };

  //Promise resolves some JSON data
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(json), 1500);
  });
};


document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  simulateFetch().then(json => {
      //Create the HTML and append it to the ul
      const liEls = json['vendor_name'].map(vendor => `<li>${vendor}</li>`);
      ulEl.innerHTML = liEls.join(' ')
    })
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
});
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data- toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu vendorDropdown">
  </ul>
</div>
```